# P/Invoke Shell_NotifyIcon supporting different NOTIFYICONDATA versions

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, notifyicon

I'm trying to invoke the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function [[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159.aspx)] from C#. One parameter of the function is a pointer to the `NOIFYICONDATA` structure [[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352.aspx)]. This structure contains `TCHAR` arrays, Pointers and also comes in 4 different versions (depending on the OS/API in use). The first field in the structure (`cbSize`) must be set to the size of the structure in bytes by the caller before passing it to the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function.

My current approach is to use 4 classes:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[BestFitMapping(false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public class  NotifyIconData { ... }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[BestFitMapping(false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public class  NotifyIconData2 : NotifyIconData { ... }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[BestFitMapping(false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public class  NotifyIconData3 : NotifyIconData2 { ... }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[BestFitMapping(false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public class  NotifyIconData4 : NotifyIconData3 { ... }
```

In the constructor of `NotifyIconData` I use `Marshal.SizeOf(this.GetType());` to determine the size of the structure. The result is correct (at least it is the same as `NOTIFYICONDATA_V1_SIZE`, `NOTIFYICONDATA_V2_SIZE`, `NOTIFYICONDATA_V3_SIZE`, `sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATAW)` in unamanged Unicode/Ansi/x86/x64 builds. The reason for this approach is that I don't want to use magic numbers especially because padding is done and therefore required to calculate the correct size of the structure.
There is also a little trick involved in the implementation of the `szTip` field. This field can either be either an array of 64 `TCHAR` characters (Version 1) or an array of 128 `TCHAR` characters (Version 2). To simulate this `NotifyIconData` class contains the following field definition:

```
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    protected string szTip;
```

In the `NotifyIconData2` class I 'extend' this field with the following definition:

```
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    private string szTipExtension;
```

The field is accessed via a virtual property which handles the segmentation of the actual value to the two fields.

Those classes are then used with the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function declared as follows:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private delegate bool ShellNotifyIconFunction(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwMessage,
        [In] NotifyIconData lpdata);
```

One would believe that I now can pass a `NotifyIconData4` instance to the function. At compile time this works (as expected). But at runtime I get a MDA `FatalExecutionEngineError` exception. When I change the paramter type from `NotifyIconData` to `NotifyIconData4` the call succeeds and it works.

It seems that the Marshaller uses the static `NotifyIconData` type instead of the `NotifyIconData4` dynamic type to marshal the data. Can anyone confirm that? Or can anyone point me to information on how marshaling works with inheritance?

Comment: Yes, the marshaller uses the declared type.  Just write overloads.  And use the .NET NotifyIcon class instead so you don't have to do this.

Comment: `NotifyIcon` is in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace - I want to avoid that. Also it does not support the GUID identifier. Also the problem is not unique to the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function, the same problem arises with other functions too (e.g. `DllGetVersion`). The strange thing is that I use the same inheritance approach with the `DllGetVersion` function and it seems to work there.

Comment: @Korexio - Why do you want to avoid System.Windows.Forms exactly?  You could also look at the source for the class itself and/or extend NotifyIcon yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound - How can I look at the source? Also, `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` is sealed. I want to avoid `System.Windows.Forms` because I don't need anything else from that assembly.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `ShellNotifyIconFunction` to accept `NotifyIconData` only the memory used by the base class is copied into unmanaged memory when the call is made. If you on the unmanaged side try to access members from the derived structs based on the contents of the `cbSize` member you are accessing data outside the bounds of the data allocated by the P/Invoke layer and this will lead to errors.

To work around this you can do your own marshalling based on the version of Windows you are running on.

Instead of declaring the second parameter of the `ShellNotifyIconFunction` as `NotifyIconData` you should declare it as `IntPtr`. You then need to allocate and manage the contents of the buffer provided when you call the function yourself:

```
var notifyIconData = new NotifyIconData4(); // Or use another version depending on the
...                                         // version of Windows.
var buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
try {
  buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(notifyIconData));
  Marshal.StructureToPtr(notifyIconData, buffer, false);
  var result = ShellNotifyIconFunction(message, buffer);
  ...
}
finally {
  if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your approach works - even when I declare `notifyIconData` as `NotifyIconData`. Can you name any references where the behavior your described in your first paragraph is mentioned? I haven't found any resources about inheritance and marshaling. The strange thing is that my first approach **does** work with the `DllGetVersion` function and the `DLLVERSIONINFO`/`DLLVERSIONINFO2` structures but that's impossible if the marshaller behaves like you said.

Comment: @Korexio: Well, I just tried to write a small native DLL and then used P/Invoke with a derived class and I saw that only the base class data was marshalled. To me it makes sense that the P/Invoke marshaller is based around the signature you specify and not run-time information.